# Подскажите как сделать такую бегущую строку?

Tags: javascript, css, jquery

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать бегущую строку как на картинке, которая бежит вокруг элемента, например вокруг картинки. Если можно, чтобы текст задавался с html элемента. Круговое движение бегущей строки, на заднем плане стока немного затухает и бежит она допустим вокруг какой-нибудь картинки. Спасибо.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. Берем фразу, бьем по символам включая пробелы.
2. Каждый символ помещаем в абсолютно позиционированный квадратный div
3. Располагаем эти квадраты вокруг цилиндра, за счет css 3д трансформаций вот таким образом (вид сверху):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

для этого:

- сдвигаем по Z в отрицательную область - это приблизит div в строну наблюдателя
- вращаем вокруг оси Y, на угол, посчитанный разбиением целой окружности на кол-во символов

  4. Крутим это все вокруг центра

```js
let chars = 'hello hello hello hello hello hello '.split('');
spin.innerHTML = chars.map((c, i) => {
  return `<div class=char style="--a:${360/chars.length*i}deg">${c}</div>`
}).join('');
```

```css
body {
  perspective: 400px;
}

.char {
  animation: rot 20s linear infinite;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin-left: -20px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  position: absolute;
}

#spin {
  margin-left: 50vw;
}

@keyframes rot {
  from {transform: rotateY(var(--a)) translateZ(150px)}
  to   {transform: rotateY(calc(var(--a) - 360deg)) translateZ(150px)}
}
```

```html
<div id=spin></div>
```

Comment: Классно, но за `.innerHTML +=` в цикле надо руки отрывать. И за отсутствие экранирования текста - тоже.

Comment: `но за .innerHTML += в цикле надо руки отрывать`
Почему?

Comment: @Qwertiy ну да, хоть это происходит и малое кол-во раз, все же не стоит подавать дурной пример

Comment: @spoon100500 каждый раз происходит рендеринг

Comment: осталось только пояснение как это работает добавить :)

Comment: я имел ввиду словами описать :) как минимум про rotate что-то написать :)

Comment: @Grundy немного описал, но боюсь кому изначально не понятно - понятнее не станет